# Quadratic equation property

Tags: roots, quadratics

It is known that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots of the equation $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=0\:$ and $x_1 < k < x_2$, $\;\sqrt{b^2-4ac}<0\;$ and $\;af(k)<0$. Why is that so?

Comment: What is x1c) and af(k)?

Comment: It's a typo, i will edit it now

Comment: You should review it again because as it stands, the statement is just wrong. Also, please use MathJax for readability.

Comment: Assume $a>0$. Then $f$ is a concave up parabola and $k$ lies between the two roots, in the negative region, so $f(k)$ is…. Then consider the case when $a<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$, by definition, denotes the nonnegative square root  of the nonnegative number $b^2-ac$, so the assertion that $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}<0$ is absurd.

What is true is this:

> If the equation $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=0\:$ has two real roots $x_1<x_2$ and if a number $k$ separates  these roots, i.e. $x_1<k<x_2$ then the *discriminant* of the equation $\Delta=b^2-4ac>0$ and $af(k)<0$, i.e. the leading coefficient $a$ and $f(k)$ have opposite signs.

The reason for the last assertion is that the existence of two roots implies a factorisation $f(x)$ as $\;f(x)=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$, so that
$$af(k)=a^2(k-x_1)(k-x_2)<0,$$ and $k-x_1>0\;$ whereas $\;k-x_2<0$.